# Cross Matching in python

Tags: python, list, search

There are two lists

```
Experimental = ["2311","1441","31","233122"]
Reference = ["asasa2311","dadewr1441","app"]
```

What I want to do is for the elements in Experimental if they match any substring in the elements in Reference then place the matching elements in Experimental in a new list.

so the new list would be

```
["2311","1441","31"]
```

what i tried doing is

```
[i for i in Experimental if any(sub in i for sub in Reference)]
```

Comment: Can you please clarify because if you only want to match a substring both `"2311"` and `"31"` would match the string `"asasa2311"`? In that case the new list would be `["2311", "1441", "31"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement doesn't match the expected output. You say "sub-string" but your expected output doesn't contain `31` even though it is sub-string of `asasa1311`. Here is one way of doing it:

```
>>> e = ["2311","1441","31","233122"]
>>> r = ["asasa2311","dadewr1441","app"]
>>> [eelem for relem in r for eelem in e if eelem in relem]
['2311', '31', '1441']
```

or if you want the expected output:

```
>>> e = ["2311","1441","31","233122"]
>>> r = ["asasa2311","dadewr1441","app"]
>>> [eelem for relem in r for eelem in e if relem.endswith(eelem)]
['2311', '1441']
```

Or if you want to be a bit more efficient to break out on the first match, use the generator approach:

```
>>> e = ["2311","1441","31","233122"]
>>> r = ["asasa2311","dadewr1441","app"]
>>> [eelem for eelem in e if any(r if eelem in relem else False for relem in r)]
['2311', '1441', '31']
```

Or a bit more shorter if we use the fact that `in` returns a boolean value:

```
>>> [eelem for eelem in e if any(eelem in relem for relem in r)]
['2311', '1441', '31']
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify the question as `31` also produced a match being a substring of `asasa1311`.

```
In [516]: Experimental = ["2311","1441","31","233122"]
     ...: Reference = ["asasa2311","dadewr1441","app"]
     ...: 

In [517]: [i for i in Experimental for x in Reference if i in x ]
Out[517]: ['2311', '1441', '31']
```

Comment: Oh forgot to clarify the Reference list dont not necessarily end with the matching substring

Comment: In that case the first suggested solution in this answer is the one you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `regex` here:

```
In [20]: e=["2311","1441","31","233122"]

In [21]: r=["asasa2311","dadewr1441","app"]

In [22]: [x for x in e if any(x in re.findall("\d+",y) for y in r)]
Out[22]: ['2311', '1441']
```

Comment: Don't have to use regex here but it's not a bad solution either. :)